# What to do with answer in FP review queue that's on a closed question

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I have run across an answer in the FP review queue which is the only answer to an off-topic question that was put on hold since the answer was posted.

My question is ... since the answer must have been floating in the review queue before the hold, what do I do with it?  Probably the question will be closed or deleted eventually, but hitting "No Action Needed" feels quite wrong, and "Skip" just punts it to somebody else.  I also thought about just downvoting it, but I almost don't want to bother as I'd rather the whole question went away.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298445/i-tried-to-make-a-ms-azure-free-trial-subscription-pending) is the question and the answer is the only one there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat it like any other answer you're reviewing in the first posts queue. Does it attempt to answer the question? Yes. Is it spam or offensive? No. Does it need to be edited? No. Then click No Action Needed.

That question (and any answers along with it) will likely be deleted soon enough because of the automatic deletion of closed questions with all posts having 0 or less score and a few other [requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519).

Comment: Does the person answering the question deserve some guidance about the types of questions to answer? post a comment. No action needed should be the *rare* first post review result rather than "meh, it looks not awful"

Comment: I guess when you put it logically like that, it seems obvious, he he. I suppose no action is needed on the answer because the necessary action has already been taken on the question.